# How to use redis as a backend for mosquitto ACL

Tags: authentication, redis, mqtt, acl, mosquitto

I am working on Mosquitto and plan to use Redis as the back end to handle both username/password pair authentication and ACL. I am using JPmens' authentication plugin to do this.

the mosquitto conf:

```
auth_opt_backends redis
auth_plugin /etc/mosquitto/auth-plug.so
auth_opt_redis_host 127.0.0.1
auth_opt_redis_port 6379
auth_opt_redis_userquery GET %s
auth_opt_redis_aclquery GET %s-%s
```

Following name/password pairs are working fine for the authentication

```
SET user1 PBKDF2$sha256$901$Qh18ysY4wstXoHhk$g8d2aDzbz3rYztvJiO3dsV698jzECxSg
```

Following settings won't work for the ACL:

```
SET user1-test 2
```

Following are the logs of mosquitto :

```
1507037072: Denied PUBLISH from mosqpub/3838-ip-172-31- (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'user1-test', ... (4 bytes))
1507037072: Received DISCONNECT from mosqpub/3838-ip-172-31-
```

So, whenever I try to pub/sub mosquitto authenticate the user but didn't allow for publishing and disconnect the user.

Testing with:

```
mosquitto_pub -p 1884 -t "test" -m "demo" -u user1 -P xyz
```

for sub:

```
mosquitto_sub -p 1884 -t "test" -u user1 -P xyz
```

Comment: Just saying it doesn't work doesen't help. You need to explain how it doesn't work, is it allowing all messages or none? What do you see in the logs when you test it? How are you testing it.

Comment: @hardillb i edited the question..So, now can you tell me whats the problem..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've worked this out.

There is an important bit missing from the logs you provided. You should have included the following line:

```
1507135115: ACL denying access to client with dangerous client id "mosqpub/2232-tiefighter"
```

The problem is the plugin is blocking because the client id contains a '/'

The following section is in the code:

```
/* We are using pattern based acls. Check whether the username or  
 * client id contains a +, # or / and if so deny access.  
 *
 * Without this, a malicious client may configure its username/client  
 * id to bypass ACL checks (or have a username/client id that cannot
 * publish or receive messages to its own place in the hierarchy).  
 */
```

The solution is to set the client id for mosquitto_sub and mosquitto_pub with the -i option e.g.:

```
mosquitto_pub -p 1884 -t "test" -m "demo" -u user1 -P xyz -i publisher
```

Comment: one more doubt, what will be the way to set the multiple topisc(acl topics) to same user in redis database.

Comment: just set multiple user-topic entries